# How to optimize on primary and secondary objective functions in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, loss-functions

I have developed a probability of loan default logistic regression model and it rank orders the risk across the deciles well, however, it doesn't rank order losses (which occur much later) well. Is there a way I can use default as the primary objective function and losses as the secondary objective function?

Comment: Why would you model losses with a logistic regression?  Losses would need another model?

Comment: Pareto optimization is the term of art you’re looking for